# Azure Devops - Detect cancelled build when using Bash

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am running the following Bash task in azuredevops.

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    FilePath: "./callback_deployment_status.sh"
```

The bash script I am calling loops through a while loop for sometime (e.g 10 mins) and waits for a job to succeeded so that it can POST the result back.
Occasionally, we manually cancel the build or job doesn't succeeded I am forced to wait whilst the bash script finishes, meaning until the 10 mins are over.

Within my bash while loop, bow can I know that somebody cancelled the build so that I can `break` out of the while loop?

```
while [ $counter -lt $total_iterations ]; do
    ((counter++))
    sleep 1  # Adjust the sleep time based on your requirements
    
    if [AzureJobCancelled==true]; then ### What does this need to be?

    fi 

done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rest api [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to get the target build result(succeed,canncelled...etc). Add a loop if the result returns null(build is still running), until it has correct result returned.

For example, to get the target build latest run result:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set variables
organization=""
project=""
definitionId=""
PAT="token"

# Initialize result as null
result=null

# Keep checking the result until it's not null
while [ "$result" == "null" ]
do
  # Get the latest build (including running builds)
  build=$(curl -s -u :$PAT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds?definitions=$definitionId&\$top=1&queryOrder=queueTimeDescending&api-version=6.0")

  # Extract the result and id
  result=$(echo $build | jq -r '.value[0].result')
  id=$(echo $build | jq -r '.value[0].id')

  # If the result is still null, wait for a while before checking again
  if [ "$result" == "null" ]
  then
    echo "Build ID: $id is still in progress. Waiting for 10 seconds before checking again."
    sleep 10
  fi
done

# Output the result
echo "Build ID: $id"
echo "Result: $result"
```

It will wait for the build to complete and return the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this worked. I assumed a system.accesstoken instead in PAT token but otherwise worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the solution you are looking for, but may be good enough if you are unable to find an answer.

Instead of adding logic in your while loop to check if the build has been canceled, you can instead add the field `cancelTimeoutInMinutes` to your task. This sill kill the task after x amount minutes when the pipeline is cancelled.

This must be defined at job level. The minimum value you can set for this is 1, the default is 5. [See more about timeouts here](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases#timeouts).

```
jobs:
  job: jobName
  cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 1
  steps:
    - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: filePath
      FilePath: "./callback_deployment_status.sh"
```